# EhCache standalone server

Tags: ehcache

I want to use EhCache standalone server. I downloaded package and started server using startup.sh in bin directory. server successfully started. Further I want to create (PUT) using REST some cache data. I tried using in terminal :

echo "Hello World" |  curl -S -T -  http:/localhost:8080/ehcache/rest/sampleCache2/3

as given in example http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/cache-server, but it giving me error : access to the resource forbidden.

What is the proper way of creating new resource?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your logs from the ehcache standalone server when you are trying to run the above command in terminal.

Comment: I already solved problem by installing earlier version of ehcache server.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by editing the web.xml you can find in the /war directory.
I had to uncomment the SOAP configuration and then I was able to use REST.